# execvp not printing anything after fgets

Tags: c

I have been trying to make some kind of "my own shell". So, what I have been trying to do is get input with `fgets()` and execute it with `execvp()`.

If I use `execvp` with an array made by me, it works as expected. However, if I try to do it with the results of `fgets` then I get no output.

```
main() {
  char str[64];
  char *array[sizeof(str)];
  char *p = NULL;
  int i = 0;

  printf("my_shell >");
  fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);  // Use fgets instead of gets.

  p = strtok(str," ");

  while (p != NULL) {
    array[i++] = p;
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }

  execvp(str, array);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a life saver!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad that worked for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by user3386109, the solution was:

> First, the array must have a NULL pointer at the end. Second, the delimiter string passed to both strtok should be " \n" (that's a space followed by a newline). You need the newline because fgets will put a newline character into your buffer, and you don't want that newline added to the array as an argument. Finally, put a perror("execvp failed"); after the execvp so that you get some indication of the problem when the execvp fails.